# Thumbnail class exceeds to much it's contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put an image inside a thumbnail class but it (the thumbnail) exceeds its contents on the left and right sides too much. 
Here is a screen shot:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vivl9.png)

And here is the code (includes bootstrap):

```
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.stutteringhelp.org/sites/default/files/pictures/alan-turing.jpg" alt="Alan Turing">
  <p class="text-center">Alan Turing: The codebreaker who saved millions of lives.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle please, so we can try it.

Comment: Or better post your code directly in your question as a snippet, as links can break over time...

Comment: here is the codepen link: http://codepen.io/ChristosMr/full/yJRvad/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to align the thumbnail

I used bootstrap's grid system creating a row for the image and the text and putting two more small empty columns on each side.

> In order to crop thumbnail to fill its contents

I did what Abhishek Pandey suggested (the second suggestion) above. That is:

```
.thumbnail {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But since the image is so small I think it is better to re-design my page than just leave it there in the middle alone.